# Parallel Processing in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following scenario in SSIS. There are two packages, Outer.dtsx and Inner.dtsx. the Inner package is called inside the Outer package in the workflow. To increase the performance, as the workload is heavy, I added a sequence container, and instead of having only one Inner package running, I managed several packages inside the container, so to have multiple instances (10 to be exact) of Inner package running in parallel. It is only one version of Inner package, however it is called several times.

How does this scenario differ from having multiple versions of Inner (Inner_1, Inner_2, ...... , Inner_10) and run them again inside the sequence container? Does having multiple packages with same definition improves the performance, compared to one version of the package, called several times ? Which scenario is more efficient and has best performance ?

Comment: To restate: If I need to have multiple instances of a package running concurrently, is there a performance difference between N instances of one package running versus N instances of N copies of the original package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of SSIS package - it is a definition of tasks and transformations written in XML format and being executed by SSIS engine. SSIS engine can execute several instances of the same package simultaneously.
On practice -- performed the following experiment. Created a dummy package loading from CSV file to MSSQL DB table with parameters of file name and table name - *InnerPkg*. Then created a copy of it - *InnerPkg1*. Also created two copies of the source file and the destination SQL Table.
**Please note!!!** I created different source and destinations to avoid resource locking.

- *OuterPkg_Parallel* calls two instances of *InnerPkg*, passing different parameters of osurce filename and destination tablename at *Execute Package Task*.
- *OuterPkg_Copies* calls *InnerPkg* and *InnerPkg1* with appropriate parameters.

Results (average of 5 runs):

- *OuterPkg_Parallel* - 12,72 seconds
- *OuterPkg_Copies* - 12,77 seconds

So, the difference is negligible, to my understanding.
The tests were conducted on MS SQL - SSIS version 2016, OS - Windows Server 2016.

**Bottom Line** - use single package calling, as it has no visible performance penalty and **greatly** simplifies support.